# Looking for a Javascript unit testing framework

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, frameworks, tdd

What do you recommend as the best and most documented Unit Test Framework for Javascript?

Comment: client side code for jquery development mostly

Comment: Is it well documented I am new to TDD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) is a BDD testing framework for javascript that works client-side or server-side.  It works well in Rails, Node, Maven, etc.  There's also a lot of plugins for things like jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery team is using its [Qunit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) for client side testing . It has a potential.

Answer (score 1):

[JSUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) is fairly useful, though it's been discontinued.

Comment: I prefer to learn something that will last a long time, do you have any other recommendations about maintained frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809/javascript-unit-testing).  JSUnit is probably very effective, but I've found that Firebug now has an extension called [FireUnit](http://fireunit.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of modules found on the [npm](http://search.npmjs.org/) if you search for "unit test".

There is also the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Unit_Testing/) testing specification.

I've written implementations of them which are on [github](https://github.com/Raynos/BrowserCJS/tree/master/Modules/test). But I wouldn't call them production ready. There reasonably stable.

Answer (score 0):

Very young, but still nicely functioning framework - [bob.js](http://www.bobjs.com).